# Can I use privileged Docker container to spawn other containers on host?

Tags: docker, privileged-functions

I have a project that consists of dozens of  dozens of containers per host. Until now, I have been using SSH/Ansible to spawn containers on my VMs on bootstrap, but now I would like a daemon to run on each host to start containers only when needed.

For better dependency management, I'd be glad if I could have my daemon run itself in a privileged container (security is not a problem), communicating with the host Docker daemon to run new containers (see the following schema). Is that possible in a non-hacky way, or does Docker completely forbid containers interacting with their underlying Docker daemon?

[image]

If this is not possible, can you tell me about your preferred way to programmatically launch docker containers? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't used privileged containers much, but I think what you are proposing would work. However, another popular solution is mounting the docker socket to the container. That will achieve what you are trying to do.

`docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock <image> <cmd>`

It's not recommended as you can see from the magnitude of recommendations against it in this simple [google search](https://www.google.se/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=mounting+docker+socket&*). But since you don't worry about security you might be fine.

Comment: This, and the api docs for the win. 

https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/

Comment: Thanks, it looks perfect. About security, I presume a daemon that can control Docker on the host is as root as a container with an exposed Docker socket, isn't it?